# Extract specific text out of bash variable containing TSV string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following TSV and newlines string assigned to a variable in bash:

```
TAGS    Product3    qwerty  text    Desc3
TAGS    Product1    qwerty  text    Desc1
TAGS    Product2    qwerty  text    Desc2
```

I would like to extract the last column to a new string, and it has to be product ordered by my product input, for example:

`Product1,Product2,Product3` will have to output: `Desc1,Desc2,Desc3`

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Expected output would be just this: `Desc1,Desc2,Desc3`

Comment: Put expected output in the question and delete comment.

Answer (score 1):

`echo "$tsv_data" | awk '{print $2 " " $5}' | sort | awk '{print $2}' | paste -sd ',' -`

This does the following steps in order:

- Print the second and 5th argument (Product and Description) with a space between them.
- Sort the input with sort (use gnu-sort if it can contain numbers)
- Print only the description (in each line)
- Join the lines together with paste

which will produce the following output:

```
Desc1,Desc2,Desc3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that I suppose should do it:

```
get_descriptions() {
    local tsvstring="$1"
    local prodnames="$2"
    local result=()
    # read tsv line by line, splitting into variables
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r tags prodname val1 val2 desc || [[ -n ${prodname} && -n ${desc} ]]; do
        # check if the line matches the query, and if, append to array
        if grep -iq "${prodname}" <<< "${prodnames}"; then
            result+=("${desc}")
        fi
    done <<< "${tsvstring}"
    # echo the result-array with field separator set to comma
    echo $(IFS=,; echo "${result[*]}")
}
```

Then you can just use it like:

```
get_descriptions "${tsv_string_var}" "product1,product2"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$var" | sort -k2 tags | cut -f5 | paste -sd,
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort` + `awk` + `paste` pipeline:

```
echo "$tsv" | sort -nk2 | awk '{print $5}' | paste -sd',' -
```

The output:

```
Desc1,Desc2,Desc3
```

---

`sort -nk2` - sorts the input by the second column numerically

`awk '{print $5}'` - prints out each fifth column

`paste -sd','` - merge lines with `,`